# The "share your answer" message beneath answers is too big

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, design, social-networking

Recently the following message started to appear beneath my answers:

[image: Screenshot of message underneath answers]

I strongly feel like the "share your answer" message consumes too much space.
The font-size is too big and inconsistent with the Stack Overflow design.
For example, the font-size is almost equal to the main title.

The social media icons besides question are much more consistent with the design.

[image: Screenshot of message besides questions]

Adding the same Icons to answers seems much better to me.

**Note**

I understand the font-size is probably increased to get my attention,
but even for this purpose, the font-size is far too big.

Comment: Having neither a twitter nor a facebook account, I can't upvote this enough! Surely it could be invisible if we don't have these accounts?

Comment: I have a Facebook account, but I can't stress how little my family and friends care if I have answered a question on StackOverflow or not...

Comment: I don't know much about interweb advertising, but I wonder; Does SE get paid (per click, or in any way at all) when users click on those "Share your foo" FB/TW ads?

Comment: +1 for the design. I'm opposed to it on a colluding level. Sure I might have 5% of FB friends who are coders but telling them about some obscure error message is either going to get my communication ignored pretty quickly or worse they will doctor site results in my favour. Just my 2 cents...

Comment: +1 Contrary to popular belief the internet does not run on social sites. Don't rub them in people's faces.

Comment: It's not that they get paid, they gegt free incoming links for better SEO. However, I do think that is should be smaller as well.

Comment: ***embarrased*** I kept slamming on the wrong add comment button, was going to make a question about it :/   So yeah, upvoting this b****.

Comment: I was about to post a question titled `"Share your answer" section is gigantic`